# How to add a cpp file to an existing project in Borland C++Builder 5?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-5

Adding the line `#include "newProc.h"` to `unit1.cpp` and `unit1.h` is not enough. It leads to an error:

> [Linker Error] Unresolved external 'newProcClass::newProc()' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\BORLAND\CBUILDER5\PROJECTS\TEST1\UNIT1.OBJ

(`newProc.cpp` was not compiled)

Make or Build Project1 with `unit1.cpp`'s line `#pragma link "newProc"` (obj) is ok, but I want to compile the `newProc.cpp` in each Make or Build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borland C++Builder 5 is very old - but I am pretty sure it still has a project view which shows the files used by the project. Right click on the project and select "Add..." and then navigate to the `.cpp` file you want to add.

If you use the main menu: File | New, and then select either VCL Form or C++ unit (the latter if you are going to develop a C++ file with no VCL GUI, can still use VCL helper functions and classes), then the file is automatically added to the project, and you don't have to do the above procedure.

Comment: Add an existing unit is done by main menu Project | Add to Project. BCB then adds an .OBJ entry to the OBJFILES line in the project .BPR file as well as adds an USEUNIT line to the project .CPP file. Header file (main unit's #include line) should be added manually. (many thanks!)